# How to prevent errors in SAS Enterprise Guide from breaking process flow links?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I use SAS Enterprise Guide (version 5.1) for several projects.  Enterprise Guide automatically creates links from programs to their input and output, which helps visualize the order of my project in an intuitive way.  However, when a program errors, it breaks the link by default, and my process flow looks like a mess - which makes it much harder to debug because I cannot spot where the initial error occurs.

Is there a way to default Enterprise Guide to keep process flow links when an error happens?

### Before Error

[image: Before Example]

### After Error

[image: After Example]

Comment: What does "breaks" mean in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only do it by adding manual links. It's really annoying and tedious, but it will pay off in the long run.

SAS has gotten a lot better about adding incremental EG updates and features. Send tech support an email requesting such a thing, and they may include it in a future release.

[image: EG process flow errors]